# Unable to link ZBar SDK with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, zbar-sdk

1. Downloaded ZBar
2. Imported the contents in to the group.
3. Added library file libzbar.a in build phases.

But when I'm tried to build (both 32 bit & 64 bit), it got the follower linker error. I have attached the screenshot of the setup in the bottom of the post.

[image]

How can I make ZBar to be flexible with both (32bit and 64 bit) Architecture.

Comment: This code doesn't work for iOS Simulator

Comment: @Tendulkar U mean the imagePicker?

Comment: No dude talking about zbar sdk

Comment: @Tendulkar Can I take it as the architectural problem will not happen in device Right?

Comment: It should compile in the device because I have tried it in xcode5 with iOS 7

Comment: Lemme try with device

Comment: @Tendulkar Can u plz add ur comment as answer so that I can accept

Comment: I have added my comment as answer

Answer (score 3):

Change "armv7, armv7s" to "armv7" only in Build Settings,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already had the same architecture in my build setting. Some inconsistency with simulators. When I was testing with device it worked very fine.

Comment: Sadly this won't probably work for much longer as Apple will be forcing all apps to require arm64 and armv7 from February 1st 2015 (I think) - armv7s will effectively become redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer to your problem just yesterday:
When I was compiling/running in simulator (64bit) or trying to create an archive with the zbar sdk (I'm using the beta 1.3.1 one), the program crashes with the same errors because of this 64bit-structure. Rest worked fine.
So I selected my project in the navigator and clicked on the project (not the target) and then Build Settings. I switched the options to ALL and COMBINED. Then I selected the drop-down-menu in Architectures / Architectures. You should see the Debug and Release options. Edit both of them and replace the $(ARCHS_STANDARD) with $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT). Now you should be able to run your project on all simulators.

One important point: I haven't tried this solution on a real 64bit device (iPhone 5s) jet. So I don't know if there might be problems with this fixing. If someone  got issues, please tell us here.

Answer (score 0):

ZBar SDK  doesn't compile when you select the `iOS Simulator` . It runs  on Device only .

Comment: It woks fine in developer mode, but when I'm trying to generate a build it showing the same error?

Comment: @ Matrosov Alexander not exactly I just removed arm7s. I don't think that as an exact solution. I faced the same issue while using google's api in some other app.